# File monitoring using syslog

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

Can rsyslog, syslog-ng programs monitor change of file? I want to monitor files and receive the changes made to the file by syslog on server. Thank you.

Comment: What type of changes do you want to monitor?

Comment: Lines added on that file etc.

Comment: Do you need to see the actual content changed or just a notification that the file changed?

Comment: It was enough clear to be _not_ closed, imho it was closed unfairly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking knowing that a syslog file is been written isn't very helpful. It's more lightly that you will be looking for certain entries, e.g root authentication or web access on certain URLs. This kind of monitoring is achieved using a log monitor. Something like Swatch or LogAnalyzer. Both have a will check the syslog for patterns & inform you when a pattern is found.

Hope this was helpful.